How do you use FLmusicLib & Godot Midi and does it work FLmusiclib Godot 4.3?
I've come across these two libraries for Godot which greatly enhance the engine's audio capabilities. Godot Midi allowing it to play and loop midi files, FlmusicLib allows it to play SPC700 tunes.
One problem, I have no idea how to use either of them to play chiptunes and midis as background music.
I'm also wondering if FLmusicLib will work in Godot 4.3 since it was originally made for Godot 3.

I recommend asking about one of these libraries at a time, since the answer for each may be different.

"Does X support Y" type questions aren't a great fit for the Stack Exchange model. If you're using one of the libraries you mentioned & ran into a problem using them for background music, I'd recommend describing what you tried and what the result was.
